# Return image without file extension in browser

Tags: javascript, php, image, url, browser

How can I 'return' to the browser an image without the file extension, something like google and unsplash does.

Example 01: https://picsum.photos/500/500

Example 02: https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/3353990143875665780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Content-type response header to that of an image (e.g. image/png) and then the response body to the content of the image.